# Where is the closest place I can sell a ship after I start a game of X3: AP?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I am looking for a place to sell one of my ships and want to know the fastest way to get there to get a decent price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are many different starts in X3:AP and most starts put you in a random sector within a part of a galaxy, its not possible to say what the 'closest place' is.  But here are some guidelines that may help:

There are a few factors that goes into selling a ship:

- Your status with the faction that owns the ship yard.  Typically the higher your rank is with them the more they'll pay for your ship.  So you'll want to find the nearest shipyard of the race you are most friendly with.
- The condition of the ship.  A ship that's not at 100% condition will sell for less.  If possible, eject from your ship (default shift+e) and use your repair laser on the space suit to fix it up before selling it.
- Equipment, when you sell a ship, you will gain 50% of the value of everything on the ship, including software and cargo.  Its more beneficial if you manually sell them rather than keep them on the ship to sell as you'll get more credits that way.

To find the nearest shipyard at your starting location, just open up communications with random ships or stations and ask them which way to the nearest shipyard.  Unless you have bad rep with that race, they'll usually direct you to them.

Finally, you can look up the location of a shipyard using the [Universe Map](http://eng.x3tc.ru/x3_tc_map/).  This is a X3:TC version but the X3:AP shipyards are in the same sectors as not much as changed between the games.